# ¿Cómo hago para que la imágen no cambie de tamaño en el carousel?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, bootstrap-carousel

Quiero colocar un carousel en el inicio de mi página pero estoy teniendo problemas con el.
He conseguido que las imágenes tengan el mismo tamaño y queden fijas en la pantalla normal pero cuando cambio el tamaño de la pantalla, la imagen se va moviendo y quiero que se quede fija tal cual está en la pantalla normal...también el texto se va hacia abajo hasta desaparecer.
¿A que se debe?
Gracias por la ayuda, un saludo!

```css
.carousel-item {
    height: 80vh;
    min-height: 300px;
    background: no-repeat center center scroll;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
     background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="assets/css/site.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Healthy Natural Juice BAR</title>
</head>

<body>
    <!--INICIO-->
    <div id="carouselExampleCaptions" class="carousel slide padding-portada" data-bs-ride="carousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="carousel-item active">
                <img src="assets/img/zumos1.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
                <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                    <h1>Zumos Naturales</h1>
                    <p>100% artesanales</p>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Ver Aquí</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img src="assets/img/tienda.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
                <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                    <h1>Horario de atención</h1>
                    <p>Lunes a Viernes 8:00 - 14:00 / 17:30 - 21:00 - Sábados y Domingos 8:00 - 21:00</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions"
            data-bs-slide="prev">
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
        </button>
        <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions"
            data-bs-slide="next">
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
        </button>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Si le das un width a tu imagen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si no quieres que la imagen vaya variando de tamaño debes quitar la clase `w-100` del elemento `<image>`. Dicha clase es lo mismo que poner un atributo `style="width:100%"` en el elemento.

Te quedaria así:

```
<img src="assets/img/zumos1.jpg" class="d-block" alt="...">
```

En cuanto al `carousel-caption`, su comportamiento es normal. Tal como indican en el [apartado correspondiente de su página web](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/carousel/#with-captions):

> With captions
>
> Add captions to your slides easily with the .carousel-caption element
> within any .carousel-item. They can be easily hidden on smaller
> viewports, as shown below, with optional display utilities. We hide
> them initially with .d-none and bring them back on medium-sized
> devices with .d-md-block.

Si no quieres que desaparezca el caption cuando el tamaño de la ventana o el dispositivo sean pequeños, debes eliminar sus clases `d-none` y `d-md-block` dejandolo así:

```
<div class="carousel-caption">
```

Comment: muchas gracias!